# pgAdmin and PostgreSQL compatibility matrix

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, compatibility-level

Has anyone ever put together a version compatibility matrix for pgAdmin versions and PostgreSQL versions?

https://www.pgadmin.org/download/windows.php

https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL versions 9.5 and above are incompatible with pgAdmin 3.

Attempting to connect gives the message:

> The server you are connecting to is not a version that is supported by this release of pgAdmin III. pgAdmin III may not function as expected. Supported server versions are 8.4 to 9.4.